# How to change the colour of a shape using ColorDialog

Tags: c#

I am creating a form which shows different images within a picture box.

I want to be able to change the colour of the shape inside using the ColorDialog box.

the problem I am having is that I am unsure what I am meant to connect the method to, to be able to change the colour of the image.

I currently using this line of code to set the Brush to black. I am using bitmap to draw the shape, too.

```
GFX.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, points);
```

Comment: Have you been able to show the `ColorDialog` and receive the chosen `Color`? If you have a color, you can make a brush using the `SolidBrush(Color)` constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.solidbrush.aspx

Comment: When I click on the button I made, the colour dialog shows but the colour isn't received. My shapes are in different classes and are called by if statements, so I was not sure how to change the colour.

Comment: "different classes and are called by if statements" is a bit vague. You might have to show a bit more code to make your code's structure clear.

Answer (score 1):

ColorDialog has the Property Color.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.color(v=vs.100).aspx

As already mentioned in the comments, you would then create a new SolidColorBrush with that Color.

```
Brush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(myColorDialog.Color);
```

Then, you'd assign that Color to your object:

```
GFX.FillPolygon(myBrush, points);
```